# If $A\approx B$ , $C\approx D$ and $A \cap C \approx B \cap D$ is it true that $A \cup C \approx B \cup D$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have noted that when $\lvert A\cap C\rvert = \lvert B\cap C \lvert = n$ for a finite  $n$ number, the proposition holds, but if the intersection is infinite, I am not sure.

I know that there are three bijections by hypothesis, $f: A \rightarrow B$. $g: C \rightarrow D$ and $h: A \cap C \rightarrow B \cap D$

I tried defining a function $L: A \cup C \rightarrow B \cup D$ as

$ L(x) =\begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if $x$ $\in A \setminus C $} \\
h(x),  & \text{if $x$ $\in A \cap C$}  \\
g(x),  & \text{if $x$ $\in C \setminus A $}
\end{cases} $

so that the first case would go to $B\setminus D$, the second to $B \cap D$ and the third one to $D\setminus B$ and as a result, $L$ would have image $B \cup D = (B\setminus D) \cup (B \cap D)\cup (D\setminus B) $. But then I realized I don't know where $f$, $g$ or $h$ are sending the elements I'm taking in  $A \cup C$, they could be sending them to the three disjoint sets I mentioned respectively , but that is probably not the case.

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, the answer is yes, since $|A\cup C|=\max\{|A|,|C|\}$ if one of the sets is infinite, and then the assumptions on the cardinalities give us the positive answer (the finite case this is true, as you noted). Without the axiom of choice it's a nice question, and I expect the answer is known. But I can't recall, and have no time to look for it now.

Comment: I believe I can't assume the Axion of Choice yet, this question is from my Set Theory course and we have not gotten there yet.

Also, $L$ doesn't work because we are not sure where the image of $f$ is in $B$, it could be in $B\setminus D$ or in $B \cap D$, same for $g$.